# For loop is taking too long

Tags: python, pandas

Edit: Here is the code above the loop for more helpful answers if it wasn't the problem.

```
import os
import pandas as pd 
import numpy 
import csv 
from math import *
ParcelSize = 50
UARFCN = 3087 

y= r"C:\Users\Heba R\Desktop\GP\Pilot1.csv"
x= r"C:\Users\Heba R\Desktop\GP\Cell.csv"

scanner_File = pd.read_csv(y) 
Cell_file = pd.read_csv(x)
Cells = Cell_file[['Cell', 'Lat', 'Lon', 'SC', 'UARFCN', 'ANT_DIRECTION']]

scanner = scanner_File[
        ['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'PSC: Top #1 (UARFCN #01)', 'Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #1 (UARFCN #01)',
         'Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #1 (UARFCN #01)',
         'PSC: Top #2 (UARFCN #01)', 'Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #2 (UARFCN #01)', 'Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #2 (UARFCN #01)',
         'PSC: Top #3 (UARFCN #01)', 'Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #3 (UARFCN #01)', 'Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #3 (UARFCN #01)',
         'PSC: Top #4 (UARFCN #01)', 'Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #4 (UARFCN #01)', 'Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #4 (UARFCN #01)',
         'PSC: Top #5 (UARFCN #01)', 'Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #5 (UARFCN #01)', 'Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #5 (UARFCN #01)',
         'PSC: Top #6 (UARFCN #01)', 'Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #6 (UARFCN #01)', 'Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #6 (UARFCN #01)',
         'PSC: Top #7 (UARFCN #01)', 'Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #7 (UARFCN #01)', 'Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #7 (UARFCN #01)',
         'PSC: Top #8 (UARFCN #01)', 'Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #8 (UARFCN #01)', 'Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #8 (UARFCN #01)',
         'PSC: Top #9 (UARFCN #01)', 'Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #9 (UARFCN #01)',
         'Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #9 (UARFCN #01)']]
scanner_size = scanner.shape[0] 
cells_size = Cells.shape[0]

def CalcDistanceM(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2): 
        lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = map(radians, [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2]) #convert decimal to rad 
        #haversine formula to calculate two points great circle distance on earth
        dlon = lon2 - lon1
        dlat = lat2 - lat1
        a = sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
        c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
        distance = 6371 * c * 1000 #radius of earth in km =6371
        return distance

def fn_CalcParcelID(Pos, ParcelUnitSize):
        if (Pos == 500):  # null parcel
            Result = int(50000000)
        elif (Pos < 0):
            Result = int(Pos * 100000) - ParcelUnitSize + (int(Pos * 100000) % ParcelUnitSize)
        else:
            Result = int(Pos * 100000) - (int(Pos * 100000) % ParcelUnitSize)
        return int(Result)

A1=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Latitude','Longitude','PSC','EcNo','RSCP'])
A2=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Latitude','Longitude','PSC','EcNo','RSCP'])
A3=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Latitude','Longitude','PSC','EcNo','RSCP'])
A4=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Latitude','Longitude','PSC','EcNo','RSCP'])
A5=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Latitude','Longitude','PSC','EcNo','RSCP'])
A6=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Latitude','Longitude','PSC','EcNo','RSCP'])
A7=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Latitude','Longitude','PSC','EcNo','RSCP'])
A8=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Latitude','Longitude','PSC','EcNo','RSCP'])
A9=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Latitude','Longitude','PSC','EcNo','RSCP'])
for i in range (scanner_size):
       #if isnan(scanner['PSC: Top #1 (UARFCN #01)'][i]) == False:
       if (scanner['PSC: Top #1 (UARFCN #01)'][i]) != -1 :
          A1 = A1.append({ 'Latitude': scanner['Latitude'][i], 'Longitude': scanner['Longitude'][i],
                            'PSC': scanner['PSC: Top #1 (UARFCN #01)'][i],'EcNo': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #1 (UARFCN #01)'][i],'RSCP': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #1 (UARFCN #01)'][i]}, ignore_index=True)

       if (scanner['PSC: Top #2 (UARFCN #01)'][i]) !=-1:
           A2 = A2.append({'Latitude': scanner['Latitude'][i], 'Longitude': scanner['Longitude'][i],
                           'PSC': scanner['PSC: Top #2 (UARFCN #01)'][i],
                           'EcNo': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #2 (UARFCN #01)'][i],
                           'RSCP': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #2 (UARFCN #01)'][i]}, ignore_index=True)
       if (scanner['PSC: Top #3 (UARFCN #01)'][i]) != -1:
           A3 = A3.append({'Latitude': scanner['Latitude'][i], 'Longitude': scanner['Longitude'][i],
                           'PSC': scanner['PSC: Top #3 (UARFCN #01)'][i],
                           'EcNo': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #3 (UARFCN #01)'][i],
                           'RSCP': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #3 (UARFCN #01)'][i]}, ignore_index=True)
       if  (scanner['PSC: Top #4 (UARFCN #01)'][i]) != -1:
           A4 = A4.append({'Latitude': scanner['Latitude'][i], 'Longitude': scanner['Longitude'][i],
                           'PSC': scanner['PSC: Top #4 (UARFCN #01)'][i],
                           'EcNo': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #4 (UARFCN #01)'][i],
                           'RSCP': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #4 (UARFCN #01)'][i]}, ignore_index=True)
       if  (scanner['PSC: Top #5 (UARFCN #01)'][i]) != -1:
           A5 = A5.append({'Latitude': scanner['Latitude'][i], 'Longitude': scanner['Longitude'][i],
                           'PSC': scanner['PSC: Top #5 (UARFCN #01)'][i],
                           'EcNo': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #5 (UARFCN #01)'][i],
                           'RSCP': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #5 (UARFCN #01)'][i]}, ignore_index=True)
       if  (scanner['PSC: Top #6 (UARFCN #01)'][i]) != -1:
           A6 = A6.append({'Latitude': scanner['Latitude'][i], 'Longitude': scanner['Longitude'][i],
                           'PSC': scanner['PSC: Top #6 (UARFCN #01)'][i],
                           'EcNo': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #6 (UARFCN #01)'][i],
                           'RSCP': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #6 (UARFCN #01)'][i]}, ignore_index=True)
       if  (scanner['PSC: Top #7 (UARFCN #01)'][i]) != -1:
           A7 = A7.append({'Latitude': scanner['Latitude'][i], 'Longitude': scanner['Longitude'][i],
                           'PSC': scanner['PSC: Top #7 (UARFCN #01)'][i],
                           'EcNo': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #7 (UARFCN #01)'][i],
                           'RSCP': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #7 (UARFCN #01)'][i]}, ignore_index=True)
       if  (scanner['PSC: Top #8 (UARFCN #01)'][i]) != -1:
           A8 = A8.append({'Latitude': scanner['Latitude'][i], 'Longitude': scanner['Longitude'][i],
                           'PSC': scanner['PSC: Top #8 (UARFCN #01)'][i],
                           'EcNo': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #8 (UARFCN #01)'][i],
                           'RSCP': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #8 (UARFCN #01)'][i]}, ignore_index=True)
       if  (scanner['PSC: Top #9 (UARFCN #01)'][i]) != -1:
           A9 = A9.append({'Latitude': scanner['Latitude'][i], 'Longitude': scanner['Longitude'][i],
                           'PSC': scanner['PSC: Top #9 (UARFCN #01)'][i],
                           'EcNo': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #9 (UARFCN #01)'][i],
                           'RSCP': scanner['Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #9 (UARFCN #01)'][i]}, ignore_index=True)
A=pd.concat([A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9],sort=False)
A = A[~A[['Latitude','Longitude','PSC','EcNo','RSCP']].apply(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()] #~ is bitwise not frozenset elem remain unchanged after creation
A.to_csv('table_data_pilot.csv',index=True)
A = pd.read_csv('table_data_pilot.csv')
#A=A.iloc[:50,:].reset_index()
A_size = A.shape[0]

for i in range(A_size):
      j = i +1
      for j in range (A_size):
         dLat=A['Latitude'][i] - A['Latitude'][j]
         dLon=A['Longitude'][i] - A['Longitude'][j]
         if abs(dLat) < 0.00045 and abs(dLon) < 0.00045:
           distance = CalcDistanceM(A['Latitude'][j], A['Longitude'][j],
                                                A['Latitude'][i],
                                                A['Longitude'][i])
           print (distance)

B1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Lat','Lon','UARFCN','PSC','SC_Avg_EcNo','SC_Avg_RSCP'])
```

First of all, I just got started in Python and therefore I do not have much knowledge. I tried to search for similar problems and I could not find a proper solution.I am using the following code:

```
for i in range(A_size):
      x1=float(fn_CalcParcelID(A['Latitude'][i], ParcelSize) )/ 100000
      x2=float(fn_CalcParcelID(A['Longitude'][i], ParcelSize) ) / 100000
      B1 = B1.append({'Lat': x1, 'Lon': x2,
                            'PSC': A ['PSC'][i],
                            'UARFCN':UARFCN,
                            'SC_Avg_EcNo':A['EcNo'][i],
                            'SC_Avg_RSCP': A['RSCP'][i]

                            }, ignore_index=True)
B1.to_csv('B1.csv')
```

The loop is meant to calculate new latitude and longitude and then making a new csv file.
A is a csv file that has almost 23000 rows and 42 column

Comment: What is the value of « A_size »?

Comment: How are you reading in the file? pandas? python's csv module?

Comment: Yes, csv module

Comment: A_size here  =23641

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should **avoid** iterating over a Pandas DataFrame using a `for` loop as much as possible.

The Pandas documentation on [Iteration](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#iteration) says:

> **Warning**
>
> Iterating through pandas objects is generally **slow**. In many cases, iterating manually over the rows is not needed and can be avoided with one of the following approaches:
>
> - Look for a *vectorized* solution: many operations can be performed using built-in methods or NumPy functions, (boolean) indexing, …
> - When you have a function that cannot work on the full DataFrame/Series at once, it is better to use `apply()` instead of iterating over the values. See the docs on function application.

Furthermore, using `append()` to add a new row to the DataFrame inside a loop is quite problematic.

Docs on [Concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html#concat) explain it:

> Adding a column to a DataFrame is relatively fast. However, adding a row requires a copy, and may be expensive. We recommend passing a pre-built list of records to the DataFrame constructor instead of building a DataFrame by iteratively appending records to it. See Appending to dataframe for more.

If you do that in a loop, then each iteration of the loop will be copying *all* data from the DataFrame to a new DataFrame, just to add the one row. Also, this operation becomes more expensive every time, since the DataFrame keeps growing and you'll have more data to copy every time.

---

In your specific case, you can easily avoid most of that, by processing A *as a whole*, generating all the rows you want to append to B1, then doing a *single* `append()` operation, meaning you only need to copy B1 once.

Putting it all together:

```
rows_to_add = pd.DataFrame({
    'Lat': A['Latitude'].apply(
        lambda x: fn_CalcParcelID(x, ParcelSize) / 100000.0
    ),
    'Lon': A['Longitude'].apply(
        lambda x: fn_CalcParcelID(x, ParcelSize) / 100000.0
    ),
    'PSC': A['PSC'],
    'UARFCN': UARFCN,
    'SC_Avg_EcNo': A['EcNo'],
    'SC_Avg_RSCP': A['RSCP'],
})
B1 = B1.append(rows_to_add, ignore_index=True)
```

This should get you from running minutes without seeing an end to having this operation complete in seconds.

You can optimize it further by implementing `fn_CalcParcelID()` using vectorized operations. (Hard to tell how to do that, since you don't show us the implementation of that function.) But the first optimization might be all you need. Ask a new question about vectorizing `fn_CalcParcelID()` if you feel that might be worth it.

---

**UPDATE:** You do have a version of the same problem with the first part of your code, where you're looping through the `scanner` CSV file and reorganizing it into A1 through A9. (You have an `A1 = A1.append(...)` inside each of those `for` loops, so you do have appends in a loop there as well!)

You can address that with:

```
A1_rows = scanner[scanner['PSC: Top #1 (UARFCN #01)'] != -1]
A1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Latitude': A1_rows['Latitude'],
    'Longitude': A1_rows['Longitude'],
    'PSC': A1_rows['PSC: Top #1 (UARFCN #01)'],
    'EcNo': A1_rows['Sc Aggr Ec/Io (dB): Top #1 (UARFCN #01)'],
    'RSCP': A1_rows['Sc Aggr Ec (dBm): Top #1 (UARFCN #01)'],
})
```

And similar for the other 8 similar DataFrames.

Comment: It didn't make any difference unfortunately, i don't know know where is the delay coming from .. i edited my question with the code above this loop if u could help me with it

Comment: @HebaR Looks like you might have the same issue in the first part of your script. At a glance, that's what it looks like. I'll try to update my answer with more when I have time. (Meanwhile, I suggest you try it yourself, to remove the `for` loops in the first part of the script.)

Comment: It is a bit different the 1st loop is a nested loop how can i do it?

Comment: Also there's no appending in that loop

Comment: @HebaR You do have appends in those loops, each of them has `A1 = A1.append(...)` or similar. Updated the answer to suggest how to handle those with a single operation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I already fixed that loop yesterday but the loop causing problem now is the nested loop that loops on i then j

Comment: @HebaR Oh yeah that's going to be awful!  Looks like you're only printing distances there (not even attached to a row) so do you really need that? Can you just drop it? In any case, this is quickly getting out of scope to your original question, so I suggest you ask a separate one about that ("How to find all points that are close to each other in a DataFrame of coordinates?" or something like it), you're likely to get better answers in a new question.

Comment: @HebaR For distances, you might want to look into the `scipy.spatial.distance` module, in particular functions `pdist` and `squareform`. You might find this article interesting: https://www.drawingfromdata.com/making-a-pairwise-distance-matrix-with-pandas

Answer (score 0):

if you are using pandas then use iterrows().

```
   for idx,row in df.iterrows():
```

Comment: It didn't make any difference.It's been 8 mins and it is still running

Comment: its not the complete code, if you paste your entire code so that i can make sure a fasterway to do that.